# Python: Encrypting and Decrypting String Without Modules using Key

Tags: python, encryption

I have a series of randomly generated strings which I need to encrypt and decrypt with a randomly generated key of the same length.

My problem is, that I can't just use PyDES or PyCrypto because I want my whole programm to be in one file and as I undrestant, modules only work if the module exists on the user's computer and the program is in the module's directory.

Can someone point me to a function, method, or even module which can be copy and pasted into and application, which encrypts with the use of a key? I would very much prefere it to involve an encryption more advanced than a Vigenere cipher but security is not my topmost concern.

Comment: Reimplementing known cryptographic functions is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Doesn't the inclusion of a private key make void that concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always just copy the implementation you find in the module into your source. Writing your own is a really bad idea though, even if you have the description of the algorithm available.

You could also use [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) to interface with an ssl library already present in the system.

Alternatively, if you know that the strings and keys are really generated using a crypto RNG, then you can just XOR them together, character by character. It's a valid one-time-pad approach. Just make sure the RNG you're using is ok for that approach. Some variants will fail hard (for example MT is easy to reverse).